# Testing an array in laravel phpunit

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I have an array output in laravel, the structure looks like follows:

```
array:1 [
  0 => {#35
    +"id": 152
    +"user_id": 123
    +"post_id": 456
    +"content": "impedit"
    +"created_at": "04-09-2016 01:24"
    +"updated_at": "2016-09-04 01:24:51"
  }
]
```

How to test the array structure contains keys `id`、`user_id` ...？

I tried assertArrayHasKey('user_id', $array)，but it shows failed. 
Thanks.

Comment: It fails because the keys in your array are `0, 1, 2, ...`. And values in the array are objects.

Comment: @linuxartisan Thanks for the reply. If I got these structure, is it possible to testing by PHPUnit ?

Comment: Try using `property_exists` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Comment: @linuxartisan Thanks a lot. I finally convert the object to array and it works well. Thanks again !

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the @linuxartisan. Finally I convert the value object to array for testing.

```
$this->assertArrayHasKey('user_id', (array)$comment[0]);
```